# Can't see themes for Multi-site wildcard subdomain

Tags: themes

I have successfully enabled wildcard subdomains and everything is working except for enabling themes besides the default. All of the plugins in the root plugin directory are available but none of the other themes I have in the theme folder are showing up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multisite set up you have to enable themes for use on the sites within the multisite.

1. Get to the network admin area by clicking on your name in the top right to open the menu and clicking 'Network admin'.
2. Go to Themes
3. Network enable any themes you want available to all your sites

If you want some themes to only be available to a single site then edit that site under 'Sites' section and go to the Themes tab, then enable the theme(s) you want for that site.